# HDMI VGA projector cannot connect to Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, vga-adapter, vga, display

Why doesn't the projector find the Macbook Pro when connecting a VGA cable to the HDMI port on Macbook Pro via an adapter? It does work on a Windows machine. I know that to fix this problem one needs to connect the VGA to the Mini Display port (via an adapter of course). So is there another way around this? Or do we have to connect to the Mini Display port.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a few months of experimentation, we found no 3rd party (i.e., non-Apple branded) HDMI <> VGA adaptors which worked well and some which *didn't work at all* on our Macs. We bit the financial bullet and purchased Apple-branded adaptors and they work perfectly.

We found the same with Thunderbolt & USB <> gig-Ethernet adaptors and Lightning <> HDMI adaptors, too. Remember, you may save $$ purchasing 3rd-party adaptors, but there are tradeoffs in either operation or quality, frequently both.

Most 3rd party adaptors have little or no strain or twist relief in the cable attachment inside the adaptor. We had slews of non-Apple Thunderbolt <> VGA adaptors die after only a week or two of use because the cables literally twisted out of the adaptor body.

Comment: Which adapter did you end up using? Apple doesn't make a direct HDMI <> VGA adapter, does it?

Comment: Apple doesn't sell them any more, as you have discovered. Since this posting (2 years old, mind you) our organization has eliminated all VGA connections and gone with HDMI. VGA is so 20th century. ;-) I suggest you look at Belkin's adaptors: https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-HDMI-Projector-Adapter-Apple/dp/B00E98QMSI

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately Belkin didn't work for me here. Maybe I can find an old Apple adaptor on Ebay.

Comment: Apple is the new Micro$oft. Time to go Linux. Lenovo Dell and System76 all do fantastic models at great prices.Bye bye non performant overly expensive locked in single vendors.

Answer (score 7):

Being that VGA is an analog signal, and (Mini) DP / HDMI are both digital signals, an adapter will be required.

Given that you wanted a solution that used HDMI, a powered HDMI port is necessary, which is not be included with the MBP, in addition Apple does not support such a configuration:

> > Can the HDMI port drive analog displays (VGA displays, for example) using adapters?
> >     No. The HDMI port will only drive digital connections (such as DVI) using the adapter that came with the Mac. The HDMI port cannot be used for analog displays such as VGA. You can purchase a Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter separately to drive analog displays.

I would think you need to do with the Mini DP converter, if VGA output is necessary. Alternatively, it is possible to get a more expensive powered active converter.

Comment: Hi, yes there is an adapter from the VGA to HDMI, and the windows machine works with this HDMI, but the MBP does not. I know the Mini Display port works but I just thought it was funny that the Win machine would work while the Mac not.

Comment: can you provide a link to the quote? I'd be interested to see the context..

Comment: @drevicko it's at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204388 (search for "Can the HDMI port drive analog displays"); and here's the [Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB572Z/B/mini-displayport-to-vga-adapter) on Apple's site.

Comment: Yes. Apple says that their HDMI output does not convert to analog like output i.e. VGA. I was facing the same issue but I had HDMI to VGA converter from J5Create. Recently, I found out that it needed a power input for the conversion Now it works like a charm. Hope you find it helpful. Thanks.

Comment: So the "Apple HDMI" is not the same as everyone else's HDMI. Apple is the Micro$oft. They should be taken to court and pay millions. Meanwhile the whole market can move to Linux and see what they think then.

Answer (score 5):

On my 2014 MacBook Pro with 2 Thunderbolt ports I found HDMI port to HDMI-VGA adapter did not work, but if I used my **Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter then plugged the HDMI to VGA adapter** into that, the VGA signal to the external monitor worked fine. Neither adapter are Apple branded, just generic.

I also had to turn off Dynamic Switching of the graphics cards (I use gfxCard Status 2.3) and use Discrete Only to prevent flickering on and off of both monitors. It still happens occasionally, but it's bearable.

EDIT: After a while the Macbook Pro intermittently stopped powering the external display, leading to both displays flickering on and off more often. Maybe I will try an Apple adapter or a different monitor with HDMI input.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which product you have, but I own an Insignia HDMI to VGA adapter. There's a micro-USB port on the adapter which I need to plug into a power source, and it then works.

I just plug it into my computer for the power and have a USB hub on the other side for my USB needs.

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: So active adapters work, then it could be that HDMI of the Mac does not make analog output (only digital signals, so no VGA compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

I also have an HDMI to VGA adapter and it doesn't work on my Mac, it does on my Raspberry Pi, haven't tried a PC yet.

There is a high probability that its Apple's System Integrity Protection that's stopping 3rd party adapters from working.

This can be disabled, see [How to Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless) in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/).

I was attempting to get a USB to Ethernet adapter working on my MacBook Pro 2015 running El Capitan and it wouldn't work. I disabled this feature and added the driver for the adapter and it worked. See [How to use a Generic USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor RD9700 on Mac OS 10.11 El Capitan](http://inkandfeet.com/how-to-use-a-generic-usb-20-10100m-ethernet-adaptor-rd9700-on-mac-os-1011-el-capitan).

There was a down side though, after this was installed the adapter caused my mac to crash twice. It was causing Kernel panics and wouldn't start hence the name System Integrity Protection.

Since I've restored without it I haven't had problems, it could of been the driver so you could just disable System Integrity Protection and see if it works.

Comment: Unless the HDMI to VGA adapter needs a special driver, I see no reason why disabling SIP would help.

Answer (score 0):

I found ICY BOX model IB-AC502 HDMI to VGA connector and works on my MacBook Pro 13 Retina, model 2015. The connector costs about 25EUR.

Answer (score 0):

A third party DVI-D to HDMI cable worked just fine. Unfortunately no luck with the VGA cable.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm the answer of **user3735534** works.

Here's what happened in my case. I used to have a Toshiba laptop with VGA port to connect to my VGA monitor. When I upgraded to Mac Book Pro, I gave away the Toshiba but not the VGA monitor.

I purchased an HDMI to VGA adaptor. The brand is **Sandberg**. It's a small square plastic box which has the HDMI cable protruding on one end and the VGA slot on the other end. This adaptor also has a small slot on one side for the micro-usb.

After connecting the HDMI and VGA, Mac Book Pro detected a second display (in settings, I could choose to mirror or extend the display). But the VGA monitor stayed black - no display at all. I used the micro-usb port of the adaptor and plugged the USB end to my Mac Book Pro. The VGA monitor then came to life. Now I'm using it as an extended display.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).  Flagging for removal as not an answer. - From Review

Answer (score -3):

Please use Thunderbolt connector
.

Comment: The Thunderbolt connector is the same as the Mini Display port ...